# Angular 9 Add click event to dynamic buttons

Tags: angular, angular-components, dynamic-html

I have buttons that I need to add for a toolbar and I can't seem to properly add a click event to them without it feeling like a hack.

Here is how I setup/return my buttons:

```
    export class ImportButtons {
      getButtons(): ButtonItem[] {
         return [new ButtonItem({
                 group: 'imports',
                 section: 'admin',
                 name: 'Approve',
                 class: 'btn btn-primary approve-all-button',
                 text: 'Approve',
                 hasMenu: true,
                 menuClass: 'approve-all-menu',
                 subItems: [new SubItem({ value: 'Approve All' })]
              }),
              new ButtonItem({
              group: 'imports',
              section: 'admin',
              name: 'OnHold',
              class: 'btn btn-primary on-hold-button',
              text: 'On Hold',
              hasMenu: true,
              menuClass: 'on-hold-menu',
              subItems: [new SubItem({ value: 'On Hold All' }),
              new SubItem({ value: 'Revert from On Hold' }),
              new SubItem({ value: 'Revert All from On Hold' })]
             })
           ];
      }
    }
```

This is in my html that grabs these and displays them:

```
    <agc class="btn-group dropdown drop-button-container" ngbdropdown="" placement="bottom-right" ng-reflect-placement="bottom-right">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let buttons of this.fillTable('import', 'admin')">
           <ng-container *ngIf="buttons.hasMenu === true">
               <button class="{{buttons.class}}" type="button" (click)="buttonClicked( buttons );" > {{buttons.text}} </button>
               <button aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split admin-split-button icon-fa-caret-down" data-toggle="dropdown" ngbdropdowntoggle="" type="button" aria-expanded="false"></button>
               <ng-container *ngFor="let sub of buttons.subItems">
                 <agc class="dropdown-menu" ngbdropdownmenu="">
                 <span class="dropdown-item c-pointer" (click)="buttonClicked( buttons, sub )" >{{sub.value}}</span>
                 </agc>
               </ng-container>
           </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </agc>
```

I currently tried calling a method when clicked ('buttonClicked()') where it tells me what was clicked. But when I click a button I see the rest of the buttons blink as if it was doing a PostBack. Because of this it feels like a hack.

Is there a correct way of doing this? Each button added will have it's own method to call when clicked (obviously) and I couldn't find a way to use a string in the click event.

For instance I initially had in my button class a 'click' property where I would put the method name to call - so "click = 'onHoldClick($event)'"  and the html click would look like "(click)='{{ buttons.click}}'"   but it didn't like that.

the html iterates through the buttons it grabs from method 'fillTable' and it looks like this:

```
    fillTable(groupName: string, section: string): ButtonItem[] {           
       switch (this.page.currentPage) {
         case 'imports':
           return this.importButtons.getButtons().filter(n => n.section === section);
         case 'export':
           return this.exportButtons.getButtons().filter(n => n.section === section);
         case 'sales':
           return this.salesButtons.getButtons().filter(n => n.section === section);
         case 'bom':
           return this.bomButtons.getButtons().filter(n => n.section === section);
       }
     }
```

Comment: Hi ! Did you tried (click)="buttonClicked($event) ?

Comment: Hi @yanesof__ I did try that and doesn't do anything. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the *ngFor when you use a function. I suggest use an auxiliar variable

```
this.buttonsActual=this.fillTable('import', 'admin');

//and make the *ngFor using 
<ng-container *ngFor="let buttons of buttonsActual">
```

You can try also use trackBy

BTW, your idea is correct `(click)="buttonClicked(button)"`. Well, you can pass only the button.name or whatever. Then you has two aproach, use a large switch in the function

```
buttonClicked(button)
{
   switch (button.name)
   {
      case "...":
      break;
      case "...":
      break;
      ...
   }
}
```

Or store in an object the diferrencs functions

```
command={
  one:this.function1
  two:this.function2
}
function1(){..}
function2(){..}
//and in buttonClicked
buttonClicked(button)
{
   command[button.name]();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am currently handling it with a switch to determine what was clicked. If that is a sound way of doing it I'll keep it and go with that. I do like your idea on storing it in an object, kind of cool way of doing it. I'll keep this up a little longer to see who else opines.